# Initial value of datepicker (angular-ui) isn't shown

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use the following code

```
<pre>Selected date is: <em>{{tournament.startDate | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>
<input name=startDate" id="startDate" type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="tournament.startDate" is-open="popup1.opened"
                         ng-required="true" close-text="Schließen""
                         datepicker-options="dateOptions" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                     <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
```

and my controller

```
$scope.tournament = Tournament.get({id: $routeParams.id});

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        dateDisabled: false,
        formatYear: 'yy',
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),
        startingDay: 1
    };
```

The value of tournament.startDate is shown in the pre-Tag but not in the input field. The opened datepicker show the correct date.

It seems to be a synchronized problem, cause if I change the controller to

```
$scope.tournament = new Object();
$scope.tournament.startDate = new Date();
```

the date is shown in the input field.

Edit: The scope is filled with the correct date but the inputfield don not show the value.

Thanks for help
chokdee

Comment: what is typeof(tournament.startDate) , when sync is not happening ?

Comment: don't understand this question.

Comment: you are getting scope.tournament from server. Can you do " console.log(typeof(tournament.startDate)" , after you get value from server.
It looks like a case of type mismatch.

Comment: Oh It seems, you already solved it :)

Answer (score 4):

Found it by mself, that the REST Service give back a String not a Date object, after converting it it's working fine.

But in my opinion angular-ui should raise an exception if the cannot convert the given object.